# solving/approximating integral of standard normal cdf

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the integral,

\begin{equation}
\int_a^b\Phi(x)dx
\end{equation}

where $\Phi(x)$ is the standard normal cdf, evaluated at $x$ (i.e., $\int^x_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$).

The reason I am trying to do this is because, I have a pdf that contains the integral of a normal cdf. Its exact form its more complicated and is not relevant to this question. Nevertheless, being able to efficiently compute the outer integral would be great. This would idealy involve expressing it in a form that most software could efficiently solve/approximate.

The answer was suggested to be, $x\Phi(x) - \int x\Phi'(x)dx$, which I assume would lead to $x\Phi(x)$. However when computing this, it does not give the correct answer,

```
# define function to integrate standard normal
> intN01 = function(x) x*pnorm(x)
# integrate standard normal using intN01 function
> intN01(2) - intN01(1)
[1] 1.113155
# integrate standard normal using numerical approximation
> integrate(pnorm, lower = 1, upper = 2)
[1] 0.9251752 with absolute error < 1e-14
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of each line of your code? including the functions.

Comment: comments are now indicated using #

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using integration by parts:
$$
\int_a^b A\frac{dB}{dx}dx = AB|_a^b - \int_a^bB\frac{dB}{dx}dx
$$
Setting $\frac{dB}{dx} = 1$ and $A=\Phi(x)$ gives:
$$
\int_a^b \Phi(x)dx = x\Phi(x)|_a^b - \int_a^bx\frac{d\Phi(x)}{dx}dx = x\Phi(x)|_a^b - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_a^bxe^{-x^2/2}dx = x\Phi(x)|_a^b +\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{-b^2/2} - e^{-a^2/2}\right) \neq x\Phi(x)|_a^b
$$

which resolves the issue. The code should look (roughly) like this:

```
intN01 = function(x) (x*pnorm(x) + (1/sqrt(2*Pi))*exp(-x*x/2))
```

Evaluating for the interval $a=1$, $b=2$, gives:
$$
\int_1^2\Phi(x)dx = \underbrace{x\Phi(x)|_a^b}_{\approx1.113155} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{-2^2/2}-e^{-(1)^2/2}\right)}_{{=-0.18798\pm0.00001}} \approx 0.925175242
$$

Comment: I now see my mistakes. Thanks for taking the time to help. Great answer!

Comment: Thanks, if you liked it, consider marking it as an answer