# Anti-derivative of Lognormal CDF

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^b\Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma)dx
\end{equation}

where \begin{equation} \Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma) = \int^x_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}y}\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\right)dy \end{equation} is the lognormal cdf, evaluated at x.

I found a solution to this question in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041186/solving-approximating-integral-of-lognormal-cdf).
It says the function \begin{equation}I(x) = x\Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma) + L(x)\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}L(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{(\mu+\sigma^2)/2}\mbox{erf}\left(\left(\sigma - \frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)/\sqrt{2}\right)\end{equation}
is the anti-derivative of the LogNormal CDF.

This makes sense to me as because of $\frac{d}{dx}\mbox{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x²}$ we get

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} L(x) &= -\frac{1}{2}e^{(\mu+\sigma^2)/2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma - \frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2}}\\
&= -\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\mu+\sigma^2)/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma^2 + \left(\frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 - 2(\log(x)-\mu)\right)}\\
&= -\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\mu+\sigma^2)/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}e^{\log(x)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu}\\
&= -\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\\
&= -\frac{1}{\sigma}\varphi\left(\frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right).
\end{align}

which implies that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}I(x) &= \Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma) + x\frac{d}{dx}\Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma) - \frac{1}{\sigma}\varphi\left(\frac{\log(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
&= \Phi_{LN}(x, \mu,\sigma).
\end{align}

In order to test this result I wrote the following short R Script.

```
erf <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1

L_function<-function(x,mu,sigma){
  z<-(sigma^2-log(x)+mu)/sigma
  z<-z/sqrt(2)
  y<-0.5*exp(0.5*(mu+sigma^2))
  return(y*erf(z))
}

I_function<-function(x,mu,sigma){
  return(x*plnorm(x,meanlog = mu,sdlog = sigma)+L_function(x,mu,sigma))
}

integral_over_LogNormalCDF<-function(lowerBound,upperBound,mu,sigma){
  return(I_function(upperBound,mu,sigma)-I_function(lowerBound,mu,sigma))
}

ded<-2
limit<-3
mu<-1
sigma<-3

n=10000
steplength=0.0001

lognormalCDF<-seq(from=ded,to=limit,by=steplength)
lognormalCDF<-plnorm(lognormalCDF,meanlog = mu,sdlog = sigma)
weights<-replicate(length(lognormalCDF),steplength)
simulated<-lognormalCDF %*% weights
funcValue<-integral_over_LogNormalCDF(ded,limit,mu,sigma)
```

The results are fine (i.e. `simulated` equals `funcValue`) except when $\mu \neq 0$.

For example:

1. $\mu=10$ -> simulated = 0.00123 and funcValue=0.002579
2. $\mu=1$  -> simulated = 0.488 and funcValue=0.540
3. $\mu=-1$  -> simulated = 0.738 and funcValue=0.667

Does anyone see my mistake?

Thanks in advance
Mathias

Comment: How do the values compare when $\mu=1$? (Are you sure the differences are large enough to not reflect rounding, or the imprecision of numerical integration?) What about $\mu=-1$?

Comment: You could edit your question to share them.

Comment: I don't yet see the mistake however using numerical integration in *Mathematica* agrees completely with the simulated values and not with the `funcValue`.  So I suspect it has something to do with `funcValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `I_function` is not correct.  Your *R* code should be more like the following.

```
erfc <- function(x) 1 - (2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1)

I_function<-function(x,mu,sigma){
  return(  (x*erfc((mu - log(x))/(sqrt(2)*sigma)) - 
         exp(mu + sigma**2/2)*erfc((mu + sigma**2 - log(x))/(sqrt(2)*sigma)))/2)
}

integral_over_LogNormalCDF<-function(lowerBound,upperBound,mu,sigma){
  return(I_function(upperBound,mu,sigma)-I_function(lowerBound,mu,sigma))
}
```

The test values you used result in the following:

```
integral_over_LogNormalCDF(2,3,10,3)
# 0.001231376
integral_over_LogNormalCDF(2,3,1,3)
# 0.4879823
integral_over_LogNormalCDF(2,3,-1,3)
# 0.7376231
```

Comment: Hi JimB, thank you for your help! Much appreciated!